# How can I stop primer from eating my roller handles?

Tags: tools, painting, primer

Whenever I use primer, it seems like I get about one room's worth of coverage before the roller handle seizes up, so that I'm pushing the roller along the wall instead of rolling it.  I'm conscientious about cleaning my painting tools immediately after use; I've tried cleaning the handle during use too, but this still happens.

Is there any way to prevent this, or should I just buy cheaper roller handles for priming, and keep the higher-quality tools for the paint (where I don't have this problem)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better roller frame may actually be the right solution. I used [this roller](http://www.homedepot.com/Paint-Brushes-Rollers-Trays/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xihZar6o/R-100357410/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) to paint most of my house after giving up on the cheap ones. It does a pretty good job of sealing the ends so that paint doesn't get inside to the rotating components. It's also got bearings to help it roll smoothly. 
[image]

Unfortunately, I've used it only with Behr interior eggshell paint, *so I can't tell you how it will do with primer*.

**EDIT:** Mike B. reports good results with primer for the same roller.

Comment: +1 for the Wooster Roller.  Very strong frame and reliable.  I used it for both priming (cheap PVA brand) and painting (various Behr brands) throughout my 1400 SQFT house.  No hiccups.

Comment: @Mike B. Thanks for the input concerning primer performance for the roller. I rolled it into the answer.

Comment: +1  I have also had similar problems with the rollers seizing up in the past, and when I upgraded to this (or a very similar) roller, I didn't have that problem anymore.  It works great with both primer and paint.

Comment: That did the trick.  I spent the weekend priming with one of these, and the roller handle was still moving freely when I checked it this morning.